# Time and Space algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am coding brute force approach for one coding problem - I need to count the maximum score path in the array with maximum step *k*.

*Input: nums = [1,-1,-2,4,-7,3], k = 2
Output: 7
Explanation: You can choose your jumps forming the subsequence [1,-1,4,3] (underlined above). The sum is 7.*

And I encountered a problem with calculating complexity. My thought was that on each elemnt we may call function *k* times, so time and space are *O(k^n)*, where *n* is length of the array. My second guess: for first element we call function at most 1 time, for second 2 times (that is if k > i) and so on. So we have sum *1 + 2 + ... + k + k + ... + k* = ((1 + k) / 2)k + ((k + k) / 2) / (n-k) = O(k^2). I think the first one is correct, but I can't tell for sure why :/

Here's my Java code:

```
public int maxResult(int[] nums, int k) {
    return maxResult(nums, k, nums.length - 1);
}

private int maxResult(int[] nums, int k, int index) {
    if (index == 0)
        return nums[0];
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int start = index - k < 0 ? 0 : index - k;
    
    for ( int i = start; i < index; i++ ) {
        int res = maxResult(nums, k, i);
        System.out.println(i);
        max = Math.max(res, max);
    }
    return max + nums[index];
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you get to O(k^2); i think that should be O(n*k), which would be the complexity of the DP algorithm. O(k^n) would be a recursive algorithm without any memoization.

Comment: There is a `println(i);` after each recursive call to `maxResuklt`. Have you tried to count the lines? How many are there, for a few different input sizes?

Comment: @tobias_k since for the first element we call function at most 1 time, for 2 - at most two times , .., for m element at most min(m, k) times and so on. So got 1 + 2 + .. + k + k +... +k, split in two algebraic series and got O(k^2). But this seems wrong now because it really takes more time than that. And if I gor you right, without optimization ( like code above ) we have O(k^n) because for every element we call recursive funcion at most k times? And space complexity will be the same?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yep, takes 19 calls for array of length 6 and k is 2, 24 calls for 7 elemntsa and k is 2. And 36 calls on 6 elements and k = 4.  I belive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence relation for your code for a particular k is

```
C(n) = sum(C(n-i) for i = 1...k) for n>k
C(n) = C(1) + C(2) + ... + C(n-1) for n <= k
C(1) = 1
```

These are the recurrence relations for the [higher-order Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_numbers_of_higher_order), shifted by k-1 places. That is, C(n) = kFib(k, n+k-1). The k-Fibonacci numbers grow as Theta(alpha^n) where alpha is some constant based on k -- for k=2, alpha is the golden ratio, and as k increases, alpha gets closer and closer to 2. (Specifically, alpha is is the positive root of (x^k - x^(k-1) - ... - x - 1)).

Therefore C(n) = kFib(k, n+k-1) = Theta(alpha^(n+k)).

Because alpha is always less than 2, O(2^(n+k)) is a simple correct bound, although not a tight one.